# Calculating expected profit from a game

Tags: probability

I have thought of a game and I’m trying to work out what the expected profit would be for either the host or the player of the game.

The game is;

You pay £5 to play and you flip a coin. If you land on heads you move to the next pay bracket, if you land on tails you lose but leave with the money in the pay bracket that you’re in.

- 0 heads - £0,
- 1 head - £2,
- 2 heads - £4,
- 3 heads - £8,
- 4 heads - £16,
- 5 heads - £32,
- 6 heads - £64,
- 7 heads - £128,
- 8 heads - £256,
- 9 heads - £512,
- 10 heads - £1024,
- Etc …

Would this be a profitable game for the player or the host of the game?

Thank you for your help :)

Comment: infinitely profitable for the player :-)

Comment: @Tortar or worth less than $50$ pounds, because you can't expect the casino to actually pay out $~\displaystyle 2^{(100)}~$ pounds.  This is an old Martin Gardner math puzzle, where, besides the issue of diminished utility (i.e. being risk averse), no one can pay out an infinite amount of money.

Comment: right, I'd like to play it with a  central bank not a casino :D

Comment: It is essentially the [St Petersburg game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/St._Petersburg_paradox)